Vue.js router.push changes URL but RankerDetail component doesn't update on button navigation
I'm developing a Vue.js application with vue-router and facing an issue with my RankerDetail component. This component is meant to display different data based on the route parameter id. When I manually enter the URLs (e.g., /Ranker/1, /Ranker/2) in the browser, the RankerDetail component correctly displays the respective data. However, when using navigateToNextCase() and navigateToPreviousCase() methods to navigate, the URL in the browser changes (from /Ranker/1 to /Ranker/2), but the component does not update to show the new case's data.
This is how the router.js is configured:
const routes = [
    // Other routes...
    { path: '/Ranker/:id', name: 'RankerDetail', component: RankerDetail, props: true, meta: { requiresAuth: true } },
];

Here are the relevant route configurations and navigation methods:
function navigateToPreviousCase() {
  const currentId = parseInt(route.params.id);
  if (currentId > 1) {
    const previousId = currentId - 1;
    router.push({ name: 'RankerDetail', params: { id: previousId } });
  }
}

function navigateToNextCase() {
  const currentId = parseInt(route.params.id);
  const nextId = currentId + 1;
  router.push({ name: 'RankerDetail', params: { id: nextId } });
}

The issue seems to be with the view not re-rendering after the route parameter changes through the navigation buttons, even though the URL in the browser updates correctly. This problem does not occur when entering the URLs directly in the browser.
How can I ensure that the RankerDetail component refreshes and displays the correct data when navigating through the navigateToNextCase() and navigateToPreviousCase() methods? What might be causing the component to not react to the route parameter change when navigating via these methods?

What is RankerDetail and what exactly does "does not update to show the new case's data"? It's not supposed to be remounted, so in case you relied on that, that's the problem

Sounds like your component is missing reactivity. Watch the route param in your component and handle it accordingly, e.g. refetch data from your backend with the new id.

I was able to solve the problem by adding the key $route.fullPath to the <router-view>. In the the main component where <router-view> is used (in my case the App.vue), update the  tag as follows:
<router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>

This modification forces Vue to treat each route as a unique instance, thus re-rendering the component whenever the route changes. The $route.fullPath ensures that the key is unique for each different path, triggering a re-render of the router-view and its child components, which in my case, will ensure that RankerDetail is properly reloaded and displays the updated content.

Even though this works, you should avoid it, since it will force all components to reload, therefore loosing their state and/or sending unnecessary requests although they did not change. If you want to use key to force-rerender you should place it as close to the component in question as possible to limit the number of components rerendering.

Method 1 :
You can use the watch function on the params passed in the router URL.
The params can be checked using the router object [const router = useRouter()] as follow
router.currentRoute.value.params.id

When any change in param is occurred, update the values or call any API to update values as per your requirement.
Method 2 :
Not recommended
You can use the JavaScript window object to reload the whole page after
router.push() is called.
window.reload()

